# XamlWriter.Save foreach properties in object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am tring do something like this:

```
 private List<ICards> selectedCards = new List<ICards>();
 foreach (var card in selectedCards)
                    foreach (var item in card.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        string save = XamlWriter.Save(item);
                        tw.WriteLine(item.GetValue(card, null));
                    }
                tw.Close();
            }
```

Where ICards is interface

```
interface ICards
{
    string CardType { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int AddressIndex { get; set; }
}
```

And example :

```
class CardBizonOc : ICards
{
    public string CardType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressIndex { get; set; }
    public string Entry1 { get; set; }
    public string Entry2 { get; set; }
```

}

For this moment `string save = XamlWriter.Save(item);` throw: `You cannot serialize the type "System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo".`

How should I pull objects out of `card` to could do it?

Comment: Shouldn't you use [Serializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.8) for that ?

Comment: No, the OP has problems with serializing PropertyInfo class. What is the goal of this serializing? Write the textual representation of CardBizonOc to xaml file? Or serialize the values of each element of selectedCards?

Comment: Thanks for resposne i find solution in link from Nawed Nabi Zada. And now it work.